# Android studio installing app on phone delete another

Tags: android, android-studio

I created 2 apps and installed 1, now when I want to install the other it deletes the first. I tried changing the package name of one of the apps but it didnt work.
Can anyone tell me what to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are changing the Java package for your application, not the application ID.

Your application ID is set in your build.gradle, typically in the `defaultConfig` block.

Previously (in ADT, prior to the first release of the Gradle plugin) the two were the same and were simply referred to as the package name. Since then the two have been separated.